# How to make a Foreigne key that references NOT Primary or Unique column from another table?

Tags: t-sql, ssms, foreign-key-relationship

I have made classical Employee - Employer table that has one primary key and one foreign key. Foreign key references primary so it is a self referencing table:

```
CREATE TABLE Worker
(
    OIB NUMERIC(2,0),
    Name NVARCHAR(10),
    Surname NVARCHAR(20),
    DateOfEmployment DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Adress NVARCHAR(20),
    City NVARCHAR(10),
    SUPERIOR NUMERIC(2,0) UNIQUE,
    Constraint PK_Worker PRIMARY KEY(OIB),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Worker FOREIGN KEY (Superior) REFERENCES Worker(OIB)
);
```

Second table that should keep points for all my employees is made like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Point
(
    OIB_Worker NUMERIC(2,0) NOT NULL,
    OIB_Superior NUMERIC(2,0) NOT NULL,
    Pt_To_Worker tinyint,
    Pt_To_Superior tinyint,
    Month_ INT NOT NULL,
    Year_ INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Point_Worker FOREIGN KEY (OIB_Worker) References Worker(OIB),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Point_Worker_2 FOREIGN KEY (OIB_Superior) References Worker(Superior),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Point PRIMARY KEY(OIB_Worker,OIB_Superior,Month_,Year_)
);
```

It should enable storing grades per month for every employee. 
That is, I have two foreign keys, one for Worker.OIB and one for Worker.Superior. Also, I have a composite primary key made of columns Point.OIB_Worker, Point.OIB_superior, Point.Month_ and Point.Year_. Key is composite because it needs to disable entering grades more then once a month.

My question is:

**How to make a foreign key from Point to Worker so that any superior can have more then one employee assigned to him?**

If you look closely, my implementation works but it can have only one employee per manager.
That is because of a fact that  a foreign key has to reference either the primary or the unique column from other table. And my Worker.Superior is UNIQUE, so it can have only unique values (no repetition).

I think many people will find this example interesting as it is a common problem when making a new database.

Comment: Why did you make Worker.Superior UNIQUE?

Comment: Why do you need the `Point.OIB_Superior` column? Isn't it redundant, since you can get the superior by joining with `Worker`?

Comment: @GilM Well, as it says in text, for a column to be a foreign key for some other column in a different table, referenced column has to be either unique or primary

Comment: @MichaelLiu I have to enable entering grades only once and only for appropriate managers that supervise the employee

Comment: I think your FK_Point_Worker_2 should also have  References Worker(OIB), and you should remove the UNIQUE constraint from Worker.Superior.  That way a superior can have more than one worker assigned to him.

Comment: @GilM Thanks, this solves it, how can I give you points?

Comment: Think about it.  You have  unique constraint on SUPERIOR and you are confused as to why two employees cannot have the same SUPERIOR.  That is what a unique constraint does - not allow duplicates.

Comment: @AntunTun, I copied my comment to be an answer so that you can mark it.

Comment: @Blam, I don't think that was his confusion.  I think the mistake was thinking it was necessary to make the OIB_Superior column reference the Superior column (which would then have to be UNIQUE) rather than the OIB column.

Comment: @GilM I added an answer as I think there is more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your FK_Point_Worker_2 should also have References Worker(OIB), and you should remove the UNIQUE constraint from Worker.Superior. That way a superior can have more than one worker assigned to him.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. You have unique constraint on SUPERIOR and you are confused as to why two employees cannot have the same SUPERIOR. That is what a unique constraint does - not allow duplicates.

A FK can only reference a unique column or columns.

A FK_Point_Worker_2 with a References Worker(OIB) does not assure OIB is a Superior.

I would add a unique constraint on Worker on (OIB, SUPERIOR)
and remove the unique constraint on SUPERIOR.
It will always be unique as OIB is unique.
Then have composite FK relationship.

This is an example of a composite FK relationship

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[wfBchFolder]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_wfBchFolder_wfBch] FOREIGN KEY([wfID], [bchID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[WFbch] ([wfID], [ID])
GO
```